# Webgl with FireFox gives an invalid arguments error

Tags: javascript, webgl

For some reason this line gives an invalid arguments error with FireFox however it works perfectly fine with Chrome.

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices0), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

vertices0 is a javascript array with all the vertices. Ive alerted some of the elements before bufferdata gets called and the vertices0 array definitely has the correct data.

Comment: can you post a *small* sample somewhere like http://jsfiddle.net?